# How to stream from a server action?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, langchain, node-streams, vercel-ai

I use Next.js server actions instead of API routes to make a request to OpenAI:

`lib/gpt.ts`:

```
export async function getAISuggestion(session: Session) {
  const prompt = ...

  const { stream, handlers } = LangChainStream();

  chatModel.predictMessages(prompt, {callbacks: [handlers]});

  return stream;
}
```

The server action calls it:

`actions.ts`:

```
export async function getSuggestion(): Promise<
  ServerActionResponse<ReadableStream<Uint8Array>>
> {
  try {
    [...]

    const stream = await GPT.getAISuggestion(session);
    
    return { data: stream };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    [...]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call this server action from a client component:

`ClientComponent.tsx`:

```
"use client";

[...]

function foo {
    [...]

    const { data, error } = await getSugestion();
    
    if (data) {
      const reader = data.getReader(); 
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      let done = false;
      let text ="";      
      while (!done) {
        const { value, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
        console.log("reading", value);
        done = readerDone;
        text += decoder.decode(value);
        setAiSuggestionsText(text);
      }
    } else {
      setError(error);
    }
}
```

But apparently, you can't send a stream from a server action to a client component:

> Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. ReadableStream objects are not supported.
> {data: ReadableStream}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Next.js doesn't appear to support returning HTTP responses from server actions. You will need to use a [Route-handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) if you want to return a response object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's not entirely correct https://github.com/jherr/streaming-sa-spotify/blob/main/src/app/action.tsx